# NSButton grow-shrink animation in Cocoa macOS application in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, nsbutton

I am having a mac app in Objective-C.

In which, I want my button to animate like grow after some seconds.

I couldn't find anything in Cocoa application.

```c
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGRect pos=v2.bounds;
pos.size.height=500;
pos.size.width=500;
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:15];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
v2.bounds=pos;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I used the above code in ios to grow a button but how to make this happen in cocoa mac application?

So basically I want a grown and shrink animation of an NSButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cocoa you have a several ways of animations, you probably need to chose an appropriate for you. For instance you can use `NSAnimationContext` for this task with a code like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self runAnimations:10];
}

- (void)runAnimations:(NSUInteger)repeatCount {

    CGFloat oldWidth = self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant;
    CGFloat oldHeight = self.buttonHeightConstraint.constant;

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
        context.duration = 1.;
        self.buttonWidthConstraint.animator.constant = 500;
        self.buttonHeightConstraint.animator.constant = 500;
    } completionHandler:^{
            //change back to original size
            [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
                context.duration = 1.;
                self.buttonWidthConstraint.animator.constant = oldWidth;
                self.buttonHeightConstraint.animator.constant = oldHeight;
            } completionHandler:^{
                if (repeatCount - 1 > 0) {
                    [self runAnimations:repeatCount - 1];
                }
            }];
    }];
}
```

It is much better to animate a constraints neither operating with `bounds` directly. But if you really need to - you can adopt this code to whatever you want.

A great video about all the options you have on OSX for animations may be seen in [WWDC 2013, Best Practices for Cocoa Animation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#213), I encourage you to watch it completely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what is buttonWidthConstraint and buttonHeightConstraint?My button name is btn. How can I do this?

Comment: These are just a width and height constraints that are set on button in IB as an example. If you not using autolayout (which is kinda weird in nowadays), you may change the button bounds directly instead of changing the constraints, just like in your code. But you should use `animator` proxy property, so this property will be animated.

Comment: My button's outlet is btn but so if I give btn.animator.constant, it gives me error. Please help me.

Comment: why did you typed animator twice? :) just replace constraints setting with `btn.animator.bounds = newBounds;`

Comment: I am not getting it sorry as I am new to mac development. Can you please make me understand via code? My button's name is btn and old height,width are 130,100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82457/discussion-between-sega-zero-and-manthan).

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few examples in Swift5.

```
@IBOutlet weak var burpButton: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var rotateButton: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var flashButton: NSButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    rotateButton.wantsLayer = true
    flashButton.wantsLayer = true
    burpButton.wantsLayer = true

    flashButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 30
    flashButton.layer?.masksToBounds  = true
    flashButton.layer?.borderWidth = 2
    flashButton.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor


    rotateButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemRed.cgColor
    flashButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemYellow.cgColor
    burpButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBlue.cgColor
}



@IBAction func rotateButtonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
    runRotateAnimations(repeatCount: 10)

}

func runRotateAnimations(repeatCount: Int) {
    let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotate.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    rotate.fromValue = 0.0
    rotate.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * -2.0)
    rotate.duration = 1
    rotate.repeatCount = Float.init(exactly: 1)!
    rotateButton.layer?.position = CGPoint.init(x: rotateButton.frame.midX, y: rotateButton.frame.midY)

    //Make(sender.frame.midX, sender.frame.midY)
    rotateButton.layer?.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    rotateButton.layer?.add(rotate, forKey: nil)
}


@IBAction func burpButtonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
    runBurpAnimations()
}


func runBurpAnimations() {

    burpButton.layer?.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    let burp = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    burp.fromValue = 0.0
    burp.toValue = 1.50 //CGPoint(x: bigWidth, y: bigHeight)
    burp.duration = 0.35
    //burp.repeatCount = Float.init(exactly: 1)!
    burp.repeatCount = 2
    burp.autoreverses = true
    //burp.speed = 0.75

    burpButton.layer?.position = CGPoint.init(x: burpButton.frame.midX, y: burpButton.frame.midY)
    burpButton.layer?.add(burp, forKey: nil)

}


@IBAction func flashButtonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
    runFlashAnimations()
}

func runFlashAnimations() {
    let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    flash.duration = 0.3
    flash.fromValue = 1
    flash.toValue = 0.1
    flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    flash.autoreverses = true
    flash.repeatCount = 2
    flashButton.layer?.add(flash, forKey: nil)
}
```

I got some ideas from @SegaZero. Some from [this medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-uibutton-animations-6ce016212c6e). While the article is about iOS, it's not hard to find usable elements for macOS.